# How can I implement Social Authentication with Auth0 in Flutter?

Tags: node.js, flutter, authentication, oauth-2.0, auth0

I have searched, and it seems like I need to implement firebase in order to be able to do social authentication. So can anybody suggest how can I implement social authentication in my flutter app, so that the auth0 server that the flutter app will use, can be reused in my web app? Moreover, how to do social authentication and be able to use node js backend service instead of using firebase ?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this blog about the social login with auth0
[auth0 login](https://auth0.com/blog/get-started-with-flutter-authentication/)